# How to find unique pattern in a column and count its occurences?

Tags: r

I have a column like the following data,

```
    A, B, C, D
    B, C, 
    A, B, C, D
    B, C
    AB, ACD, GJ
```

Note that there are several letters like these: AB, BFC, TRD, RE, etc. So I need to find some automated way to give patterns as arguments.

when I issue `summary(data$column1)` , I get A, B, C, D is 2 and B, C is 2. But I want to get A 2, B 4, C, 4, D 2. How can I use the "," as the separator and accomplish this?

I also used `unique(data$column1)`. It produced just the unique values A, B, C, D and B, C but not the occurrences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
str=paste(df$col, collapse=',')
rle(sort(strsplit(gsub("[^A-Z]","",str), '')[[1]]))
```

Or as @David Arenburg proposed:

```
table(strsplit(gsub("[^A-Z]","",str), '')[[1]])
```

**Data:**

```
df=data.frame(col=c("A,B,C,D","B,C","A,B,C,D","B,C","ABBBCCDD"))
```

Comment: Note that there are several letters like these. So I need to find some automated way to give patterns as arguments.

Comment: What do you mean by "several letters like these" ?

Comment: So I also have patterns like AC, ABC, CF, etc.

Comment: @Gworld - I think you should edit your example to include those cases and what your desired result should be. That potentially changes the whole answer process.

Comment: I think you could just do `table(strsplit(gsub("[^A-Z]","",str), '')[[1]])` instead of the `sort` `rle` combination

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strsplit` like this

```
x = c("a,b,c","a,b","b,c,d,e")
table(unlist(strsplit(x,',')))
```

Since the split pattern is a regular expression, you can consume any spaces betwen the values and the commas like so:

```
table(unlist(strsplit(x,'\\s*,\\s*')))
```

Comment: @jthrope Note that there are several letters like these. So I need to find some automated way to give patterns as arguments.